# python voice signature identification?

Tags: python, voice-recognition, voice, voice-recording

I'm working on a system that locks several parts in my computer and opens them ONLY using my voice saying specific
words (in python). I've already made the system that locks parts in my computer until you give it password but I want to change it to voice.
I did find some voice processing on the web but its really complicated and without explanation
in python.
I know python might not be the right language to do so, but I want to try!

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can start from pre-built services, like [Azure Speaker Recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speaker-recognition-overview). The process is quite straightforward, you provide audio training sample for each single speaker (yourself for example). This will create an enrollment profile based on the unique characteristics of your voice. If your are looking to build a solution from scratch, then Fast Fourier Transform would be a great start.